# Filtering list by two or more selects in Vue.js 2.0

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Since in Vue 2.0 you can no longer chain together multiple pipeline filters to a list (`|filterBy` etc), how are you supposed to do this in a computed property if you have two or more select dropdowns?

I want the ability to sort by album title (from select 1) and by year (select 2).

```
<select v-model="albumFilter">
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="Album 1">Album 1</option>
    <option value="Album 2">Album 2</option>
    <option value="Album 3">Album 3</option>
</select>

<select v-model="yearFilter">
    <option value="Year">Year</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>

<ul>
    <li v-for="review in filterByAlbum" v-if="review.type === 'recordReview'">
        <a :href="review.jsonUrl">
            [[ review.title ]]
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Vue js code:

```
data() {
    return {
        pressEntries: [],
        albumFilter: 'All',
        yearFilter: 'Year'
    }
},

filterByAlbum: function() {

    // Select 1 (Album Filter)
    switch (this.albumFilter) {
        case 'All':
            return this.pressEntries;
            break;

        case 'Neither':
            return this.pressEntries.filter(entry => {
                return entry.relatedRecording === null
            });
            break;

        default:
            return this.pressEntries.filter(entry => {
                return entry.relatedRecording === this.albumFilter
            });     
    }

    // Select 2 (Year Filter)
    if (this.yearFilter === 'Year') {
        return this.pressEntries;
    }
    else {
        return this.pressEntries.filter(entry => {
            let postDate = new Date(entry.postDate.date);
            return JSON.stringify(postDate.getFullYear()) === this.yearFilter;
        });
    }
}
```

The `pressEntries` data model gets data from an API, which I didn't bother including the code for.  Each block of code for each select filter works on their own, but not together.

If the `filterByAlbum` in the `v-for` loop refers to the computed property, which then refers back to `pressEntries` data model, would it be possible to have two computed properties that the `v-for` runs through (like "`filterByAlbum`" and "'filterByYear`" for example)?  Or do I need to figure out how to filter all the results in one massive computed property?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of a computed that would work. You could move `albumFilter` and `yearFilter` into their own methods as well. Essentially using this kind of technique, you could assemble as many filters together as you wanted.

```
function filterByAlbum(){

  const albumFilter = entry => 
           (this.albumFilter == 'All') || 
           (this.albumFilter == 'Neither' && !entry.relatedRecording) ||
           (entry.relatedRecording === this.albumFilter);

  const yearFilter = entry => 
         (this.yearFilter == 'Year') || 
         (new Date(entry.postDate.date).getFullYear() == this.yearFilter);

  const reducer = (accumulator, entry) => {
    if (albumFilter(entry) && yearFilter(entry))
      accumulator.push(entry);
    return accumulator;
  }

  return this.pressEntries.reduce(reducer, []);
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
        pressEntries,
        albumFilter: 'All',
        yearFilter: 'Year'
    }
  },
  computed:{
    filterByAlbum
  }
})
```

I had to guess at your data structure, but here is a [working example](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/VpPMPz?editors=1010).

Comment: Hi if I want to count show item. How to do that ? Thanks

Comment: @KemBardly Do you mean you want to count the items that come out of the filter?

Comment: Yes, I want to do pagination please help

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution:
You can easily add a 3 Selectbox

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PjOoEN

```
function() {
    var vm = this;
    var category = vm.selectedCategory;
    var gender = vm.selectedGender;

    if(category === "All" && gender === "All") {
        return vm.people;
    } else {
        return vm.people.filter(function(person) {
            return  (category === 'All' || person.category === category) && (gender === 'All'  || person.gender === gender);     
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi if I want to count show item. How to do that ? Thanks