# Fix vue js checkbox filter

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm starting with Vue and I was reading some questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43925816/checkbox-filtering-with-vuejs) to filter with `computed()`.

I think I'm on the right path to solve my problem but I could not make it work yet.

I have a search field in my webpage to search for users according to their city. Each user have an array of filters set to `true` or `false`.

The listing process works fine. Now I want to click on filter buttons and keep in the list only users that have the clicked filter in their filters array.

html:

```
<div class="filters-div">
    <label class="btn btn-circle border filters-btn">
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="vehicle" value="vehicle" v-model="checkedFilters" />
        <i></i>
        <span>Vehicle</span>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-circle border filters-btn">
        <input type="checkbox" name="host" id="host" value="host" v-model="checkedFilters" />
        <i></i>
        <span>Hosting</span>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-circle border filters-btn">
        <input type="checkbox" name="transfer" id="transfer" value="transfer" v-model="checkedFilters" />
        <i></i>
        <span>Transfer</span>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-circle border filters-btn">
        <input type="checkbox" name="activities" id="activities" value="activities" v-model="checkedFilters" />
        <i></i>
        <span>Night Activities</span>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-circle border filters-btn">
        <input type="checkbox" name="adventures" id="adventures" value="adventures" v-model="checkedFilters" />
        <i></i>
        <span>Adventures</span>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-circle border filters-btn">
        <input type="checkbox" name="tour" id="tour" value="tour" v-model="checkedFilters" />
        <i></i>
        <span>Tours</span>
    </label>
</div>

<div v-for="(item, index) in filterHoster" v-bind:key="item.id" class="col-md-6 mb-50">
    <div class="result-container">
        <div class="result-content2">
            <div class="result-profile-pic-div2">
                <div class="result-profile-pic2 img-fluid" v-bind:style="{'background-image': 'url(http://localhost/users/'+item.profileIMG + ')' }"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="result-profile-infos-div2">
                <div class="result-name">
                    <h4 class="mb-0">{{ item.name }} {{ item.lastname }}</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="result-rating">
                    <div class="rate-area">
                        <star-rating @rating-selected="setRating(item.id, item.rating)" :rating="item.rating"></star-rating>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p>{{ item.city }} - {{ item.state }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr />
                <div class="tour-options">
                    <div class="tour-options-select">
                        <select :id="'select-suggestions' + item.id" name="tour-options-dropdown" v-model="selected[item.id]" class="tour-options-dropdown" @change="showTour = selected, setTour($event)">
                            <option :value="null">Tour suggestions</option>
                            <option v-for="(tour, key) in item.tours" :key="key" :value="tour.tourID">
                                {{ tour.title }}
                            </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

vue

```
let app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        hosters: {},
        filters: {
            vehicle: "true",
            host: "true",
            transfer: "true",
            activities: "true",
            adventures: "true",
            tour: "true",
        },
        checkedFilters: [],
    },
    computed: {
        filterHoster() {
            if (!this.checkedFilters.length) return this.hosters;

            // return this.hosters.filter(f => this.checkedFilters.includes(f.filter));

            return this.hosters.filter((f) => {
                f.filters.filter((j) => {
                    this.checkedFilters.includes(j);
                });
            });
        },
    },
});
```

This is my database response:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make some changes in my filters response:

`filters: ["vehicle", "host", "transfer", "activities", "adventures", "tour"];`

and filters in `data()` are not being used anymore.

The final `computed()` is:

```
computed: {
    filterHoster() {
        if (!this.checkedFilters.length) return this.hosters;

        return this.hosters.filter(hoster => {
            return this.checkedFilters.some(
                filter => hoster.filters.includes(filter)
            );
        });
    }
},
```

This way I can check if every checked filter is included in user filters.

Answer (score 0):

if you convert hosters to array you are good to go in my case. Because filter will not work in objects.

```
hosters: [],
```

You can check it here: https://codepen.io/hasip-timurtas/pen/QWNoNjE

Comment: Hi. unfortunately it didn't work. If I put {{ filterHoster }} in DOM to display results it get empty like before.

Comment: check {{ checkedFilters }} in DOM

Comment: It displays the `input value`. I tried using `:value="filter.vehicle"` but it throws an error. "cannot ... id of undefined" and I can't find where is this.